# Sampling a distribution (from a galaxy model)

Tags: computational-physics, galaxies, models

I am reading the following article:
http://www.kof.zcu.cz/st/dis/schwarzmeier/galaxy_models.html
and am currently at section 5.6 (positions of bodies in a galaxy).

I am trying to redo the simulations myself in Python, but I have a questions regarding sampling of the distribution.

Given a distribution function (Hernquist distribution):

$$\rho(r)=\dfrac{M}{2\pi}\cdot \dfrac{a}{r(a+r)^3}$$

the article states that to simulate the distribution, one has to calculate the mass within a circle of radius $r$ like follows:

$$m(r) = \int_{0}^{r} 4 \pi r'^2 \rho(r') dr'$$

which is the cumulative mass distribution function.

The article states that this formula represents the PDF. However, looking at the shape this appears to me to be a CDF. Approaching infinity the function approaches 1.0 which is for me a clear indication of a CDF.

To sample this distribution the article cites the Von Neumann method where one has to generate an $r$ and a $m$ value, and scale them accordingly, and check whether or not they fall below the $m(r)$ graph. If they do they are accepted, else they are rejected.

Am I completely off by thinking this is wrong? If I do this I end up with the majority of stars ending up at the higher radii.

I have the feeling I am sampling an CDF here instead of a PDF. To get accurate results (e.g.: having the majority of the stars in the center) means that I have to perform the Von Neumann method with the $\rho(r)$ function.

I am unable to contact the author of the article, so that's why I am asking here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The article looks indeed wrong. In fact, there are two mistakes.

First, you're right that the acceptance-rejection method has to be applied to $\rho(r)$, and not to $m(r)$. To understand how this idea works, suppose we want to generate a one-dimensional normalized distribution function $p(y)$. Now, let's assume we can rewrite this distribution function in terms of a variable $x$, such that it takes the form of a uniform distribution. That is,
$$
p(x) = 
\begin{cases}
1& \text{for $0\leqslant x \leqslant 1,$}\\
0& \text{elsewhere}.
\end{cases}
$$
Given $p(y)$, what is $x$? We have the Jacobian transformation
$$
p(y)dy = p(x(y))\left|\frac{dx}{dy}\right|dy = \left|\frac{dx}{dy}\right|dy,
$$
which implies
$$
p(y) = \frac{dx}{dy},
$$
assuming that $x(y)$ is an increasing function. Thus
$$
x = \int_0^y p(y')dy' = F(y).
$$
In other words, the integral of $p(y)$ (or equivalently, the area under the curve) follows a uniform distribution. With this in mind, there are essentially two ways to perform a Monte-Carlo simulation.

The first way is the acceptance-rejection method: plot the curve $p(y)$ and uniformly generate a pair of numbers $(a,b)$ in the interval $([0,y_\max],[0,p_\max])$, where $y_\max$ and $p_\max$ are the upper bounds of $y$ and $p(y)$. If the coordinate $(a,b)$ lies under the curve $p(y)$, accept it; otherwise, reject it. If the coordinate is accepted, $y=a$ is generated point.

[image]

There are major drawbacks to this method: $y_\max$ and $p_\max$ can be infinite, so one would need a cut-off. And if $p(y)$ has a sharp peak, one ends up rejecting a lot of points.

A far more efficient method is to uniformly generate $x$, and calculate the corresponding $y$ by inverting $x=F(y)$:
$$
y = F^{-1}(x).
$$
This automatically fills up the area under the curve, without rejecting points.
[image]

If the calculation of $F^{-1}(x)$ is too numerically involved, one can use a combination of both methods: introduce another (simpler) function $f(y)$ that lies everywhere above $p(y)$. Apply the inversion method to $f(y)$, generating a point $y$. Then uniformly generate a value $b$ in the interval $[0,f(y)]$. If $b\leqslant p(y)$, accept $y$; otherwise, reject it.

Now, consider the Hernquist distribution. Since it has a cusp at the origin, and the cumulative mass $m(r)$ is a simple function
$$
m(r) = M\frac{r^2}{(a+r)^2},
$$
I'd definitely recommend the inversion method. But there is an important caveat here, and that's the second mistake in the article: **$\rho(r)$ is not really a one-dimensional distribution**. Instead it is a distribution in 3-dimensional space, and it is only a function of one variable due to spherical symmetry. In order to apply the Monte-Carlo method, we have to express $\rho$ as a truly one-dimensional distribution function, which we can do by expressing it in terms of the **volume**
$$
y = \frac{4\pi}{3}r^3.
$$
Now we have
$$
p(y) = \rho(y) = \frac{M}{2\pi}\frac{a\,(3y/4\pi)^{-1/3}}{\left[a + (3y/4\pi)^{1/3}\right]^3},\\
F(y) = m(y) = \int_0^y\rho(y')dy' = M\frac{(3y/4\pi)^{2/3}}{\left[a + (3y/4\pi)^{1/3}\right]^2}.
$$
Once we generated a point $y$, the corresponding radius is 
$$r=\left(\frac{3y}{4\pi}\right)^{1/3}.$$

There is an important consequence: there are likely more particles at large radii than around the centre, even though $\rho(r)$ is much larger at small radii. The reason is that particles between two radii $r$ and $(r+\Delta r)$ occupy a shell with volume 
$$V = \frac{4\pi}{3}\left[(r+\Delta r)^3-r^3\right].$$ 
The larger the radius $r$, the larger the volume of the shell, which means you need more particles to fill it and get $\rho(r)$. This is obvious in the case of a constant density, but it is also true for general densities.

Comment: Thanks for the incredibly detailed answer! And I am glad I am right with the acceptance-rejection method :)

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, these images are from the *Numerical Recipes* text, which is copyrighted material, so you need to include references to where they are from.

Answer (score 1):

The CDF, $F(x)$, is related to the PDF, $f(x)$, via the relation:

$$F(x) = \int_{-\infty}^xdx'\,f(x')$$
In the case of radial distributions, your lower limit is obviously 0 and not $-\infty$. Thus, your CDF is $m(r)$ and the PDF is $4\pi(r')^2\rho(r')$ (technically should be $\rho(r')$ with the $4\pi(r')^2$ coming from $dx\to dr$ and spatial isotropy, but whatever).

In the case of *invertible* functions (e.g., $f(x)=Ax$ with normalization constant $A$), you can solve this as
$$F(x)=\frac{A}{2}x^2\to x=\sqrt{\frac{2F}{A}}$$
If you generate a random number number, set this equal to $F$ and out pops your $x$ that satisfies the PDF.

In the case your functions is *not* invertible (often the case involving radial distributions), I'd suggest using a [Newton-Raphson](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_method) iterative method to finding roots for this case. This can be easily done since you know $F(x)$ (your CDF) $F'(x)=f(x)$ (your PDF):
$$
x_{new}=x_{old}-\frac{F(x_{old})}{f(x_{old})}
$$
When $|x_{new}|<\epsilon$, then $x_{old}$ is the (approximate) root. Often, only a few iterations are necessary for convergence.

---

As an aside, I cannot stress enough how **terrible** a suggestion the acceptance-rejection method is. **DO NOT USE THIS METHOD**. It literally wastes computation time, something that ought to be viewed as precious, regardless of the prevalence of computers. Do not listen to anyone who says you *have* to use this method, they are completely and utterly wrong.

The Newton method I suggest above does **not** reject a single random number, will fit the PDF accurately, and is highly efficient.