# Sampling Maxwell-Jüttner distribution for non-unity mass and speed of light

Tags: special-relativity, statistical-mechanics, computational-physics, plasma-physics

I am trying to sample Maxwell-Jüttner distribution using the Sobol method as described in [Zenitani *Loading relativistic Maxwell distributions in particle simulations* (2015)](https://aip.scitation.org/doi/full/10.1063/1.4919383). Equation (2) in the paper assumes $m=c=1$ and then goes on to describe how to sample the four-velocity. I have a few questions regarding the Sobol algorithm:

1. If $m$ and $c$, are not taken to be unity, how will that affect the value of generated $u$? I can see how this will affect $f(u)$, but does $u$ also need to be scaled?
2. In order to get $v$, which the normal three velocity vector, do we just need to use the relation $u = \gamma v$, and express $v$ in terms of $u$?

I am attaching my distribution plot for reference.

[image]

Comment: Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/298469/25301

Comment: @KyleKanos Yeah I saw that post, and I don't have any problem as such in sampling. I am just confused about proper normalization, as to how should I scale my u(and therefore v), and f(u) when the mass and speed of light is not taken to be unity.

Comment: I linked a related query since it's about the same paper in both. I wasn't trying to suggest it answers your own question.

Answer (score 1):

OP's equations are
\begin{align}
f(\mathbf{u})\,\mathrm{d}^3u&=\frac{N}{4\pi m^2cTK_2(mc^2/T)}\exp\left(-\frac{\gamma mc^2}{T}\right)\,\mathrm{d}^3u\tag{1} \\
\Rightarrow f(u)\,\mathrm{d}u&=\frac{N}{TK_2(1/T)}\exp\left(-\frac{\sqrt{1+u^2}}{T}\right)u^2\,\mathrm{d}u\tag{2}
\end{align}
where $\mathbf{u}=\gamma\mathbf{v}$ is the spatial components of the 4-velocity, $\gamma$ the Lorentz factor, $N=\int f(\mathbf{u})\,\mathrm{d}u$ is the total number density, $T$ the temperature and $K_2(x)$ the modified Bessel function. The $4\pi$ factor is dropped in (2) due to use of spherical coordinates and it is plain to see that,
$$
u=\gamma v\implies \gamma=\sqrt{1+u^2/c^2}
$$

Since $u$ is the velocity, then $m\neq1$ should be straight-forward re-insertion. Additionally, since $u=\gamma v$, then there should be no changes to $u$, only to $f(u)$. Lastly, indeed you should invert the relation between $u$ and $v$ to get the 3-velocity, though the work is done for you in Zenitani's paper (and above):
$$
v_i=\frac{u_i}{\gamma}=u_i\cdot\left(1+u_i u^i\right)^{-1/2}
$$

---

In my opinion, it may not be the best of ideas to *not* use $c=1$, since using such scaling is intended for convenience (in both notation and in coding) in relativistic settings. Since the Maxwell-Jüttner distribution describes the relativistic distribution of velocities, it probably would be better to stick with $c=1$.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The reason why I am reluctant to use c= 1 is that because this sampling is part of a bigger code, and in other places, we have used c= 3e10. When I tried rescaling f(u) by $\frac{1}{(mc)^3}$ and replacing u by u/c in the definition of gamma, I am not scaled version of my original plot. New plot: 
https://imgur.com/WYY6cYA
Something tells me I need to rescale u too.

Comment: I've always been taught that you should keep units out of codes, rescaling for visualizing only (maybe not even then). $u$ will have same units as $v$, of so I don't think additional factors of $c$ is needed. I don't know why you're scaling $f(u)$ by $1/(mc)^3$, though, that's not what's called for...

Comment: The $\frac{1}{(mc)^3}$ factor comes from equation (1). Eqn. 2 is obtained by moving to spherical coordinates and setting m=c=1. So I just rescaled f(u) in Eqn (2) by replacing N by  $N * \frac{1}{(mc)^3}$ and $ \sqrt {1+u^2}$ as $ \sqrt {1+\frac{u^2}{c^2}}$. 
I think I will stick with m=c=1 to avoid any confusion.

Comment: I'm still confused. There's a clear $m^2c$ in the denominator in (1) & nothing else, so you've got a few too many factors floating there. There's also a factor of $mc^2$ in the Bessel fcn & another in the exponent, have you accounted for those?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, but I am not using T, rather I have defined a dimensionless temperature $\theta = \frac{T}{mc^2}$. So $T = mc^2 \theta $ and I can effectively replace T in exponential and the Bessel function in Eqn 1 by $\theta$. 
So equation 1 becomes 
$ f(u)  = \frac{N}{4 \pi (mc)^3 \theta K_{2}(\frac{1}{\theta})}* exp(- \frac{\gamma}{\theta}) $
I am using $\theta$ = 0.4